# \micro in package siunitx stopped working

Tags: luatex, siunitx

Using the `\micro` command in `siunitx` worked fine some months ago. But suddenly, maybe caused by software updates, some fellows and me aren't able to use `\micro` in `siunitx`.

There is no error, the `\mu` is simply not displayed in the generated  PDF-file.

We are currently using dirty workarounds such as using `10^{-6}` or `\upgreek` instead, but we are very interested in solving the problem.

We are using LuaLatex as Latex-engine on different systems (macOs and different Ubuntu distros).

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**: I am using **LuaLatex Version 1.0.4 (TeX Live 2017)**; my minimal code example, causing the error, which was working fine some months ago, is the following:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{german}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}\si{\micro}\end{document}
```

Comment: Please give specific examples, i.e., actual code, which "worked" at some point in the past and have now "stopped working". Please also tell us *which* version of LuaLaTeX you use; this piece of information is provided in the first row of the log file.

Comment: Cannot reproduce `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\si{\micro}
\end{document}` ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbbmI.png)).

Comment: `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{siunitx} \begin{document} \si{\micro} \end{document}` is fine with both pdflatex and lualatex with TL2017.

Comment: I edited my question, I have simplified my usual header as far as possible, the error seems to be caused somehow by `unicode-math`

Comment: I can reproduce the problem, it is due to a (resolved) bug in unicode-math. It will be gone with TL2018. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/411573/2388.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54915/151808), just add a `\sisetup`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{german}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{math-micro=\text{µ},text-micro=µ}
\begin{document}\si{\micro}\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. But I would like to understand, why the exact same code was working last year? What (and why) was changed in the LuaLatex-software?

Comment: Really I can't answer this question! The naive  way is another question: didn't you change your preamble adding the `unicode-math`? But you've already said `exact same code`

Comment: I have double-checked some of my old documents, with the exact same header, without using `sisetup` and I took a look in my old log-files, I was using the exact same Version of LuaLatex back then (`LuaLatex, 1.0.4 (TeX Live 2017)  (format=lualatex 2017.6.25)  14 AUG 2017 10:59`, the only difference to today is: `(format=lualatex 2018.4.19)  24 APR 2018 08:59` and I am not really sure, what this exactly means)

Comment: And, double-checked it too, we were using the same header back then. `unicode-math` was included in my preamble. When I recompile my old files without adding `\sisetup` every `\micro` disappears. Magic! :)